# Unity C#'Matrix3x3' does not contain a definition for 'GetRow'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm implementing a simple GetRow and GetColumn on matrix3x3 in Unity with C# language but I get the `'Matrix3x3' does not contain a definition for 'GetRow' and no accessible extension method 'GetRow' accepting a first argument of type 'Matrix3x3' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` error. Does anyone know where this issue is coming from?

Comment: Is your code written in the C# language or UnityScript language?  Please show your failing code.

Comment: It's in C#, 
```Matrix3x3 a = new Matrix3x3(Vector3.right,Vector3.up,Vector3.forward);
Debug.Log(a.GetRow(0));
```

Comment: In that case, I've removed the UnityScript tag for you.

Comment: Please show your code .. if this is [`Matrix3x3`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.tiny@0.16/api/Unity.Tiny.Math.Matrix3x3.html) well .. nope it doesn't have `GetRow` nor `GetColumn` ...

Answer (score -1):

The error you're getting simply means that you are trying to use something that isn't accessible or doesn't exists.

In your case, `GetRow(int)` doesn't seem to exists. Are you sure you've implemented `GetRow(int)`? If you did, make sure you saved your files before recompiling in Unity.

You can read more about the error [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1061)

> #### To correct this error
>
> 1. Make sure you typed the member name correctly.
> 2. If you have access to modify this class, you can add the missing member and implement it.
> 3. If you don't have access to modify this class, you can add an extension method.

### EDIT:

You said *implementing*, as in, writing it yourself, but if you are using `Matrix3x3` from any library that isn't yours, and GetRow doesn't exists, then you could simply implement it using **extension methods.**

Ex.

**Matrix3x3Extensions.cs**

```cs
public static class Matrix3x3Extensions
{
    public static Vector3 GetRow(this Matrix3x3 matrix, int rowIndex)
    {
        if (rowIndex < 0 || rowIndex > 2)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(rowIndex), "Row index must be between 0 and 2.");
        }

        switch (rowIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                return new Vector3(matrix.M11, matrix.M12, matrix.M13);
            case 1:
                return new Vector3(matrix.M21, matrix.M22, matrix.M23);
            case 2:
                return new Vector3(matrix.M31, matrix.M32, matrix.M33);
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(rowIndex), "Row index must be between 0 and 2.");
        }
    }
}
```